# ios swift uitableview sections with different tabledata

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a list of data coming in from json. With this list I would like to load it into a tableview but within two seperate sections called Featured and All. Trying to figure out how to get my "Featured" section not to load the same amount of rows as the "All" section. All section is good but Featured section shows Featured list plus 16 empty rows. Any ideas on how I get rid of these extra rows in the Featured section?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return "Featured"
    }
    return "All"
}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    var sections: Int = 2
    return sections
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var count: Int = tableData.count
    println("tabledata \(count)")

    return count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    let entry : NSMutableDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary

    var featured = entry["Business_IsFeatured"] as? String

    if ((featured == "1") && (indexPath.section == 0))
    {
        var busName = entry["Business_Name"] as? String
        var points = entry["Member_Points"] as? String
        var imageName = entry["Business_Image"] as? String
        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/images/\(imageName!)")!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
            request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
            completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    cell.textLabel!.text = busName
                    cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
                    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Points: \(points!)"
                    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
        })
    }
    else
    {
        if((featured == "0") && (indexPath.section == 1))
        {
            var busName = entry["Business_Name"] as? String
            var points = entry["Member_Points"] as? String
            var imageName = entry["Business_Image"] as? String
            var imgURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/images/\(imageName!)")

            cell.textLabel!.text = busName
            cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Points: \(points!)"
            cell.imageView!.hnk_setImageFromURL(imgURL!, format: Format<UIImage>(name: "original"))
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tomsoft and @ScorpioCurse I was able to get the featured section to load up the correct data by making two seperate arrays for the data. Before I was trying to return count which swift wasnt liking. After changing it to return a separate array tableFeatData.count else return tableData.count I got it working. I also had to add a second dictionary. Code below. I may still need to clean up some of this code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    let entry : NSMutableDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary


    var featured = entry["Business_IsFeatured"] as? String

    if ((featured != "1") && (indexPath.section == 0))
    {
        let featentry: NSMutableDictionary = self.tableFeatData[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
        var busName = featentry["Business_Name"] as? String
        var points = featentry["Member_Points"] as? String
        var imageName = featentry["Business_Image"] as? String
        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/images/\(imageName!)")!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
            request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(),
            completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    cell.textLabel!.text = busName
                    cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
                    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Points: \(points!)"
                    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: data)

                }
        })
    }
    else
    {
            var busName = entry["Business_Name"] as? String
            var points = entry["Member_Points"] as? String
            var imageName = entry["Business_Image"] as? String
            var imgURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/images/\(imageName!)")

            cell.textLabel!.text = busName
            cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Points: \(points!)"
            cell.imageView!.hnk_setImageFromURL(imgURL!, format: Format<UIImage>(name: "original"))
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of UITableViewDataSource's

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

method needs to supply the number of rows you intend for each section to contain. Your code returns the same number of rows regardless of the section, which sounds wrong based on how you describe what you want to do. You need to calculate and return the number of featured items for your Featured section, rather than the size of your entire dataset.

Comment: I tried supplying a different set of data dependent on section but it kept crashing on me.

Comment: @Jackson There's not much anyone can do to help without some details on the code you added and what is crashing. Based on your code in the question, one simple way to test this would be to just do a loop through the table data and count how many items have "Business_IsFeatured" set to "1" then return that. There are better ways to model your data than a dictionary representation of the JSON and those could yield more efficient solutions, but this should be a starting point anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The "tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int" function is here for this. Depending of the section, you return the numbers of rows into this section

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   if(section==0){
    var count: Int = tableData.count
    println("tabledata \(count)")
    return count
  }else{
   return theOtherData.count
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I gave this a shot myself earlier but just gave it another shot after seeing your code. Keep running into a crash. `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var count: Int = tableData.count
        if(section==0){
            
            println("tabledata \(count)")
        
            return 3
        }
        return count - 3
    }`

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: @Jackson That's debugging, the error is pretty clear: your array  is empty and you try to get first element. So is it normal that your array is empty?